# Creating a system:time_start propery from scratch

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am attempting to generate some zonal statistics for a feature layer, approximately following the steps outlined in [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/extract-raster-values-for-points#zonalstatsfc_params_%E2%87%92_eefeaturecollection).

The ImageCollection I am using comes from the [Awesome GEE Catalog](https://gee-community-catalog.org/projects/fabdem/) and apparently does not contain any `system:start_time` properties for any items in the collection. When I try to call the zonal statistics function from the tutorial linked above, I get an error for

> Element (Error)
> Collection.first: Error in map(ID=Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N00_00_E006_00_DEM):
> Image.date: Image 'Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N00_00_E006_00_DEM' does not have a 'system:time_start' property.

I've tried to manually set a `system:time_start` property here:

```
//Bare Earth Elevation
var fabdem = ee.ImageCollection("projects/sat-io/open-datasets/FABDEM")
.filterBounds(fextent);
print(fabdem.first())
var test = fabdem.mosaic();
var test2 = ee.ImageCollection(test)
test2.set("system:time_start",'2023-02-13T19:33:07+00:00')
print(test2)
```

To simplify things, I took the original ImageCollection (which is not time sensitive) and flattened it to a mosaic, then recreated an ImageCollection as the `zonalStats()` function requires one. the output still does not contain a system:time_start property. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the format was incorrect for my `set()` command.

```
//Bare Earth Elevation
var fabdem = ee.ImageCollection("projects/sat-io/open-datasets/FABDEM")
.filterBounds(fextent);
print(fabdem.first())
var test = fabdem.mosaic().set("system:time_start",ee.Date('2000-01-01').millis());
var test2 = ee.ImageCollection(test)
print(test2)
```

using set on the mosaic before recreating the ImageCollection did the trick.